Pass data to next view using Binding<T?>
I need some help from my colleagues because I can't handle it on my own. I am stuck.
I have a database on Firebase with training programs in it. ProgramsID loads the list of trainings. Here's how the data is structured:
struct SportProgramModel: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let author: String
    let shared: Bool
    let trainingDays: [TrainingDayListValues]
}

struct TrainingDayListValues: Codable, Identifiable{
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var trainingDayType: trainingDaysTypes
}

enum trainingDaysTypes: Codable{
    case workout (TrainingDayModel)
    case rest (String)
    
    var workout: TrainingDayModel?{
        get{
            switch self {
            case .workout(let trainingDayModel):
                trainingDayModel
            case .rest:
                nil
            }
        }
        set {
            if let newValue{
                self = .workout(newValue)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TrainingDayModel: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var title: String
    var setOfExercises: [SetOfExercisesModel]
}

struct SetOfExercisesModel: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    let title: String
    let setOfExercises: [ExersiseModel]
    let isSingle: Bool
    let sets: String 
    let rest: String 
}

struct ExersiseModel: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    let exerciseDetails: [ExerciseDetailsModel]
    let repeats: String 
    let weight: String 
    
}

struct ExerciseDetailsModel: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    let workoutGroup: String
    let workoutType: String
}

I want the user to be able to edit each element if they need to, so I decided to use Binding<T?>. If an element doesn't exist, I create an empty one that the user can fill in. In the previous topic, Sweeper helped me understand how to pass data to the next view.
SwiftUI change list value with enum associated values and arrays on different view using Navigation link
But I still don't understand how to pass Binding<T?> for the next view.
Can you please advise me? Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way? Is there a better way to do it? Here's my code:
First view with modelView:
import SwiftUI

@MainActor
class SportProgramViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var sportProgram: SportProgramModel?
    @Published var trainingDaysList: [TrainingDayListValues] = []
    
    func getSportProgramDetails(sportProgramID: String) async {
        do{
            let sportProgram = try await SportManager.shared.getSportProgram(id: sportProgramID)
            self.trainingDaysList = sportProgram.trainingDays
        } catch {
            print("Error when getting sport program")
        }
    }
}

struct SportProgramView: View {
    @ObservedObject var sportProgramViewModel = SportProgramViewModel()
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    @State private var title = ""
    @State private var description = ""
    @State private var author = ""
    @State private var shared: Bool = false

    @State private var isLooped: Bool = false
    @State private var restDays = ""
    @State private var showRestDayView: Bool = false

    var sportPorgramID: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            VStack {
                TextField("Name your program", text: $title)
                Divider()
                TextField("Enter descripton", text: $description)
                Text("author id" + author)
                
                Toggle(isLooped ? "Looped" : "Time-bound", isOn: $isLooped)
            }
            .padding(50)
            
            List{
                ForEach($sportProgramViewModel.trainingDaysList){ $day in
                    switch day.trainingDayType {
                    case .workout(let workout):
                        NavigationLink {
                            TrainingDayView(trainingDay: $day.trainingDayType.workout)
                        } label: {
                            Text(workout.title)
                        }
                    case .rest(let rest):
                        Text("Rest for " + rest + " days")
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            
            // Create new empty sport program
            HStack {
                NavigationLink{
                   TrainingDayView(trainingDay: nil) 
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.app.fill")
                        Text("Add day")
                    }
                }
                
                if !isLooped{
                    Button{
                        showRestDayView.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        HStack{
                            Image(systemName: "pause.rectangle.fill")
                            Text("Add rest")
                        }
                    }
                    .alert("Add rest days", isPresented: $showRestDayView){
                        TextField("Rest days", text: $restDays)
                        Button("Add"){
//                            sportProgramViewModel.addRestDay(days: restDays)
                        }
                        Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear{
            //if we have id it means its not a new sport program
            if let id = sportPorgramID{
                Task{
                    await sportProgramViewModel.getSportProgramDetails(sportProgramID: id)
                    // fill the TextField is there exist direct way? 
                    title = sportProgramViewModel.sportProgram?.title ?? ""
                    description = sportProgramViewModel.sportProgram?.description ?? ""
                    author = sportProgramViewModel.sportProgram?.author ?? ""
                    shared = sportProgramViewModel.sportProgram?.shared ?? false
                }
            }
        }
        .toolbar{
            Button {
                Task{
                   guard let user = UserManager.shared.firebaseAuth.currentUser.userId else { return }
                    await sportProgramViewModel.saveSportProgram(user)
                    dismiss() 
                }  
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("New program")  
    } 
}

#Preview {
    SportProgramView()
}


Second view with viewModel:
import SwiftUI

@MainActor
class TrainingDayViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var setOfExercses: [SetOfExercisesModel] = []
    
}

struct TrainingDayView: View {
    @StateObject var trainingDayViewModel = TrainingDayViewModel()
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var trainingDay: Binding<TrainingDayModel?>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            if let title = trainingDay.wrappedValue.title {
                TextField("Name your day", text: title) // error her :(
            }
            
            List{
                // how to fill list from Binding<t?> and pass data to next view using NavigationLink?
            }
            .toolbar{
                Button {
                    dismiss()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


#Preview {
    TrainingDayView(trainingDay: .constant(nil))
}

Third view with viewModel:
import SwiftUI

@MainActor
class SetOfExercisesViewModel: ObservableObject{

}

struct SetOfExercisesView: View {
    @StateObject var setOfExercisesViewModel = SetOfExercisesViewModel()
    
    var setOfExercises: Binding<SetOfExercisesModel?> //Not working :(
    
    @State var title: String = ""
    @State var sets: String = ""
    @State var rest: String = ""
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            VStack{
                TextField("title", text: $title)
                TextField("sets", text: $sets)
                TextField("rest", text: $rest)
            }
            .padding()
            
            List{

                //here i also need fill data from pervious view and pass in next with NavigationLink
            }
        }
        .toolbar{
            Button{
                dismiss()
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Add exercises in set")
    }
}


#Preview {
    SetOfExercisesView(setOfExercises: .constant(nil))
}

I've already tried unwrap value with extension
public extension Binding {
    func unwrap<T>() -> Binding<T>? where T? == Value {
        if let wrappedValue = wrappedValue {
            return Binding<T>(
                get: { wrappedValue },
                set: { self.wrappedValue = $0 }
            )
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    func wrap() -> Binding<Value?> {
        Binding<Value?>(
            get: { wrappedValue },
            set: {
                if let value = $0 {
                    wrappedValue = value
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

But its not working for next view, and values not saving.

Use @Binding`

Replace ViewModel with .task
